# Space-orderings for the space-like, light-like and time-like vector can be altered

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, group-theory, parity

My question concerns the space-ordering for the space-like vector between two space-time points in the Lorentz invariant theory:
$$ (t_1,\vec{x_1}) \text{ and } (t_2,\vec{x_2})$$

Is it correct to claim that:

> 1. Regardless for

> - a space-like vector  $(t_1-t_2)^2-(\vec{x_1}-\vec{x_2})^2<0$,
> - a light-like vector  $(t_1-t_2)^2-(\vec{x_1}-\vec{x_2})^2=0$,
> - a time-like vector  $(t_1-t_2)^2-(\vec{x_1}-\vec{x_2})^2>0$,

> it is always possible to do a Lorentz transformation, such that the time-ordering of two events, at $t_1$ and $t_2$, may switch their time-ordering?

Suppose $ (t_1,\vec{x_1}) \text{ and } (t_2,\vec{x_2})$ can be Lorentz transformed to
$ (t_1',\vec{x_1'}) \text{ and } (t_2',\vec{x_2'})$,
or $ (t_1'',\vec{x_1''}) \text{ and } (t_2'',\vec{x_2''})$.
Of course,
$$(t_1-t_2)^2-(\vec{x_1}-\vec{x_2})^2=
(t_1'-t_2')^2-(\vec{x_1'}-\vec{x_2'})^2=
(t_1''-t_2'')^2-(\vec{x_1''}-\vec{x_2''})^2.$$

> 2. Namely, it is always possible to find the case that their space-ordering can be altered:
>    $$
>    x_1-x_2>0, \quad x_1'-x_2'=0, \quad x_1''-x_2''<0?
>    $$

What is the proof or argument?

Comment: All three of your questions could have been combined into one question being that they are so closely related to one another.

Answer (score 1):

**Changing Sign**

With a boost, $x' = \gamma(x - vt)$ so $\Delta x' = \gamma(\Delta x - v\Delta t)$. To change sign, the product of before and after should be negative (signifying a sign change): $0 > \Delta x' \Delta x = \gamma(\Delta x\Delta x - v\Delta t \Delta x)$, requiring:

$v\Delta t \Delta x > \Delta x \Delta x > 0$.

so

$|v\Delta t|>|\Delta x|$

If $|v\Delta t| < |c\Delta t| <= |\Delta x|$ (spacelike or light-like interval) this clearly won't work. But for timelike $|c\Delta t| > |\Delta x|$ it will.

So, what should we do about the spacelike and light-like cases? Well, a cop-out. Just change the order of $x_1$ and $x_2$ without a boost with an [improper transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Improper_transformations). Parity-swap the order.

**Zero**

To transform to $x_1'=x_2'$ or $\Delta x' = 0$, look to the interval

$\Delta t^{2} - \Delta x^{2} = \Delta t'^2 >= 0$

So only time-like or light-like are possible, and light-like only in the case that $\Delta t' = 0 = \Delta x'$.